# Spring Transactional Management PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT

Tags: java, spring

I have following log, Do I need to take this error into account? 
Is there a problem with my transaction configuration?

Using Spring 3.1.1

```
[DEBUG]-2015-03-17 14:45:18,957 DataSourceTransactionManager: Creating new transaction with name [com.mydao.updateUserInfo]: 
PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; '',-java.lang.Exception
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This string is built in `toString()` method of `DefaultTransactionDefinition` class. According to the documentation, the `toString()` method generates the description for transaction definition and the format matches with `org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeEditor`.

`TransactionAttributeEditor` generates the String in following format

> PROPAGATION_NAME, ISOLATION_NAME, readOnly,
>   timeout_NNNN,+Exception1,-Exception2
>
> A "+" before an exception name substring indicates that transactions
>   should commit even if this exception is thrown; a "-" that they should
>   roll back

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think there is an error ?

The line just trace the creation of a transactionManager with it's configuration. The `java.lang.Exception` printed here is probably the value of the `rollbackFor` parameter (exception type which will trigger a transaction rollback when occurring).  Exception is the default value here.